# mouse over image swap

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I need help with a mouse-over issue.

In the div container, I have three images side-by-side. I need to have a image swapped that covers the entire area of the three images when the users mouse hovers over any three of the images.

Each time the user hovers over one of the three images, I need to have one of the large images replace the smaller image. The images are here:

So, if the user hovers over the image labeled "engage: then the large "engage" image will show up where all three images are. Same for the other two images.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/GaryBoutwell/QzbSQ/

```
<div align="center">
<div id="multiple" class="swap">
<img class="left" src="http://www.delphidisplay.com/NewDesign/img/image1.jpg" />
<img src="http://www.delphidisplay.com/NewDesign/img/image2.jpg" />
<img class="right" src="http://www.delphidisplay.com/NewDesign/img/image3.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="single" class="swap">
<img src="http://www.delphidisplay.com/NewDesign/img/image1-1.jpg" />
</div>



$('.swap').hover(function () {
    $('.swap').toggle();
});
.swap {
    width: 893px;
}
#multiple {
    text-align: center;
}
#single {
    display: none;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

I hope I explained it enough,

Thanks,

Gary

Comment: following your posted code, sorry, i've no idea...

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle sample, it may improve your chances to get help.

Comment: Hi Gary, welcome to stack overflow.  Please read the section about how to ask questions.  You need to show us what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the big image in a separate container with the same size as the container with the three images, and then toggle the visibility of the containers when you hover over either of them.

```
$('.swap').hover(function(){
    $('.swap').toggle();
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TL6Ef/2/)

Comment: Thanks, my apologies for not providing more details on what I have tried. Here is the page: http://www.delphidisplay.com/NewDesign/default.html

Comment: My answer still applies. Add another div with the big image, hide it by default, and toggle the visibility of both of them on hover. Did you see my fiddle? What don't you understand about it?

Comment: THANKS!! Even though I didn't provide enough info, you solution worked!! Mega thanks!

Comment: OK, I think I spoke too soon.  What I want to accomplish is when the user hovers over any one of the three images, another full size image will appear the covers the entire area where the three images are. For example, if the user hovers over the first image (the engage image) then a fill width image will appear, same for the second and third image. The 1st swap image is here: http://www.delphidisplay.com/NewDesign/img/image1-1.jpg Please take a peak at the code on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GaryBoutwell/QzbSQ/ - Thanks in advance. (P.S. creating websites is not my regular gig)

Comment: I went ahead and updated your fiddle. Basically what I did is made the id of each small image correspond to a CSS class of the big image. Then when you hover over either of them, toggle the big image div and also the small image container div. I didn't have the other 2 big images so I just used placekitten. :) See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QzbSQ/2/

Comment: You are beyond awesome!! Works exactly how I wanted. I can't thank you enough!! Have a great weekend!